# VirtualBox + Vagrant: How to adjust the size of HardDisk

Tags: vagrant

I create a ubuntu vm in Vagrant with command-line tool. I find that the hard disk is dynamic allocation, and the default value is `40G`.

How can I adjust the size? (I want to change it smaller.)

I've tried to find it in the official documents, but I failed. Maybe the minimal value is `40G` ?

Comment: why do you need smaller ? Its dynamic as you said so it only grows on your host hard drive if the VM grows - when you boot the VM for first time, the vdi file are quite small

Comment: @FrédéricHenri The virtualbox's disk has cost 40GB in my host disk size, and the  actual size  of ubuntu is less than 5GB.

Comment: @pl_rock thanks! I think it can resolve my problem.